# how to improve the performance of seek when using avplayer

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, avplayer, seek

I'm using `AVPlayer` to create a video player, but the `seekToTime` method is pretty slow. I'm impressed by the seeking performance of Apple's app "Photos". Does anyone have any idea how Apple managed to do such a quick seeking?

Does it has anything to do with threads? I tried to put the `seekToTime` call in a dispatch queue, it does't help either.

Comment: If you would provide some sample code of your implementation, I think people rather know what could be improved.

Comment: Hi @kcpac, actually, I have find the solution. I trying to let user scrub through a video using a slider control. If I use `seekToTime` to do the scrubbing, it's pretty slow. What I should use is a method called `stepByCount` from `AVPlayerItem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution.

If I use `seekToTime` to do the scrubbing, it's pretty slow. What I should use is a method called `stepByCount` from `AVPlayerItem`.

Comment: give example of `[playerItem stepByCount:x];` what we need in place of x to start same video again.

Answer (score 0):

This code is taken from: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1820/_index.html

It helps a little and seek forward looks smooth. But seek backward still tooks too many time (here [SeekToTime working smoothly just for forwards, freezy on backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575419/seektotime-working-smoothly-just-for-forwards-freezy-on-backwards) is explanation why).

```
import AVFoundation
 
class MyClass {
 
    var isSeekInProgress = false
    let player = <#A valid player object #>
    var chaseTime = kCMTimeZero
    // your player.currentItem.status
    var playerCurrentItemStatus:AVPlayerItemStatus = .Unknown
 
    ...
 
    func stopPlayingAndSeekSmoothlyToTime(newChaseTime:CMTime)
    {
        player.pause()
 
        if CMTimeCompare(newChaseTime, chaseTime) != 0
        {
            chaseTime = newChaseTime;
 
            if !isSeekInProgress
            {
                trySeekToChaseTime()
            }
        }
    }
 
    func trySeekToChaseTime()
    {
        if playerCurrentItemStatus == .Unknown
        {
            // wait until item becomes ready (KVO player.currentItem.status)
        }
        else if playerCurrentItemStatus == .ReadyToPlay
        {
            actuallySeekToTime()
        }
    }
 
    func actuallySeekToTime()
    {
        isSeekInProgress = true
        let seekTimeInProgress = chaseTime
        player.seekToTime(seekTimeInProgress, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero,
                toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero, completionHandler:
        { (isFinished:Bool) -> Void in
 
            if CMTimeCompare(seekTimeInProgress, chaseTime) == 0
            {
                isSeekInProgress = false
            }
            else
            {
                trySeekToChaseTime()
            }
        })
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Achieving smooth seeking like what Apple is able to do in its standard iOS user interface requires a combination of several tricks:

1. As said [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66335096/760435) you need to chain seeks without cancelling pending ones. This is essential as otherwise the player won't be able to move forward if seek requests keep getting cancelled.
2. The player must be paused during the seek operation. You can restore the intended playback rate when the last seek request ends.
3. Depending on `AVPlayerItem` declared capabilities you should [adjust seek tolerances](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1388493-seektotime) as follows:

- If the item returns `true` from [`canStepForward`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1389656-canstepforward) then seek with `.zero` for both tolerances. This provides for a step-by-step seek user experience for such content.
- If the item returns `true` from [`canPlayFastForward`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1389096-canplayfastforward) then seek with `.zero` as `toleranceBefore` and `.positiveInfinity` as `toleranceAfter`. This ensures that the player can use available I-frame playlists for a snappier seek user experience (trick mode).
- Otherwise just seek with `.positiveInfinity` for both tolerances, as this ensures the player can reach the desired location as fast as possible (but without additional benefits).

Note that the above is not officially documented by Apple AFAIK. I simply had a look at `AVPlayerViewController` behavior on iOS 16+, observing how the attached `AVPlayer` is used when seeking within different kinds of streams.

You can check our implementation on [GitHub](https://github.com/SRGSSR/pillarbox-apple/pull/466) for implementation details.